# Trouble in deserializing JSON data from CoinGecko API

Tags: c#, json, api, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm having an issue while getting some JSON to deserialize.
It's coming in via HttpClient from CoinGecko API.

This is the URL:
[GetSimplePrice](https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin%2Cethereum&vs_currencies=usd%2Ceur&include_market_cap=false&include_24hr_vol=false&include_24hr_change=false&include_last_updated_at=false&precision=1)

It returns:

```
{
  "bitcoin": {
    "usd": 28352.7,
    "eur": 26185.8
  },
  "ethereum": {
    "usd": 1821.4,
    "eur": 1682.2
  }
}
```

Special-Pasting the above as JSON into C# creates these classes (works):

```cs
public class Rootobject
{
    public Bitcoin bitcoin { get; set; }
    public Ethereum ethereum { get; set; }
}

public class Bitcoin
{
    public float usd { get; set; }
    public float eur { get; set; }
}

public class Ethereum
{
    public float usd { get; set; }
    public float eur { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Working Attempt (static)]

However, the name of the coin and the currency are dynamic fields so I can't use that exactly as is.

I've tried the below and while the deserialization works, my class returns empty:

```cs
public class SimplePrice
{
    public Coin Coin { get; set; }
}

public class Coin
{       
    public float Price { get; set; }
}
```

[image: Non-Working]

I've been banging my head against a wall for a while on this one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JSON, you should deserialize as `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, float>>` type.

```cs
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, float>> simplePrice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, float>>>(json);

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, float>> coin in simplePrice)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Coin: {coin.Key}");

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, float> price in coin.Value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{price.Key}: {price.Value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Duh, so simple! 
I overcomplicated everything and got tunnel vision.
This was kicking my butt, thank you so much!